# Fixed footer of a UItableview. always at the footer position

Tags: iphone, uitableview, css-position, table-footer

Im trying to have a footer Fixed at the bottom of a uitableview. it will always be at the bottom, not scrollable with the table cells. It also cant cut out and cells like cover the last cell of a uitable view so one cell will be hidden. I have the following header file:

```
//fooer contains a number_of_total_clicks label, an a proceedtopayment button. 
@interface checkout : UITableViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *number_of_total_clicks;
- (IBAction)proceedtonextview:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *footer; //?
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *items_clicked;
@end

and in my .m file

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //self.tableView.tableFooterView= footer; ??
    number_of_total_clicks.text=@"0";
}

//void or IBAction?V
- (void)add_item_to_array_of_clicks_which_will_increment_number_of_total_clicks_value:(id)sender{
    number_of_total_clicks.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f",[sender doubleValue]*5];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

What happens is I get a footer the is basically attached to the last cell of the table so if the table has only 3 cells, the "footer" with the number_of_total_clicks will be attached as a 4th cell. if there are 45 cells, he footer will be he 46th cell only accesible once I scroll all the way down. I want it o be fixed a the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `-loadView` method try manually creating your view using `[UIScreen mainScreen]. applicationFrame` as the frame. Note that you should use a `UIView`, not a table view.
This view will fill the whole screen (except for tab and navbars, when using them).

You can then manually add a `UITableView` as the VC's `tableView`, but don't make it fill the whole view. Leave some space at the bottom, just as much to fit your 'table footer' in. Remember to set the `tableView` to have a flexible width as well as a flexible height.

Now for the 'table footer' just add it as a subview to `self.view` (not `self.tableView`) and place it at the very bottom of `self.view`. This view should have a flexible width and a flexible top margin.

I hope this fits your needs.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate? Im having trouble doing it programatically. how do I place it at the very bottom of self.view?