# XCode: can't drag/drop UIView onto a UIViewController in interface builder

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

In the master-detail application template for iPad in XCode 4.3, the master view (side pane navigation menu) extends a UITableViewController. I instead want it extend a UIViewController and make use of UIView & a UITableView to show the master table ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247213/206613)!).

The problem I am facing is that I can't drag & drop a View object onto MasterViewController class (which extends UIViewController). Can't this be done using the interface builder? The best I have been able to do is drag/drop the UIView at same level of MasterViewController not inside it. 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the standard table view controller with a view controller in the default application, do this:

1. Select the master UITableViewController
2. Press `delete` to delete it.
3. Drag a UIViewController from the Objects panel onto the canvas.
4. control-drag from the master navigation controller to the new UIViewController
5. Select "Relationship - Root View Controller".

Note:  In your other post you said that you want to combine a UIView and a UITableViewController.  Just a word of warning:  If you are using static cells in the table view, it **must** be embedded in a UITableViewController and it **will not work** in a UIViewController.  (You **must** use dynamic cells if you are going to do it this way).  In your particular case, you may not need the table view at all though.

Comment: @Inafziger Nice! You answered the question a bit too general though (replacing the controllers). Had to do a bunch of other things for the template to work with a custom master view, like removing the code that handles the tableView. Thanks